# JADE export to Executable jar from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, executable, agents-jade

I need to export my project to a executable jar file and I have been working in Eclipse.
My main class is currently Jade.Boot, From there a run the arguments -agents starter:Agents.initialiser
I am having difficulty running the Jar after creating it.
I am also getting this error when I try to export the jar:
    Could not find main method from given launch configuration.

Please note the program runs completely fine in eclipse it is just that I need to run it as an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set the Run configuration of your project? Because if you did, you will be able to select this configuration when you export your project to an exectuable jar file.

Good luck.